# HTML table correctly use and set mat-select in columns of table

Tags: html, html-table, angular7

I have this table:

```
<table class="mat-elevation-z8">
              <tr>
                  <th align="left" mat-header="nomeFile"> Nome file </th>
                  <th align="left" mat-header="note"> Note </th>
                  <th align="left" mat-header="tipoDocumento"> Tipo documento </th>
                  <th></th>
                </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let documento of documenti" class="mat-row">
                <td> {{documento.nome}} </td>
                <td> {{documento.note}} </td>
                <td> <mat-form-field class="col">
                    <mat-select formControlName="tipoDocumento" [(value)]="tipoDocumentoSelezionato">
                      <mat-option value="generico">Allegato Generico</mat-option>
                      <mat-option value="verbale">Verbale</mat-option>
                      <mat-option value="esito">Esito Analisi</mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                  </mat-form-field> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

The problem with this implementation is that, whenever I choose an option in a row of my table, all the other rows in the table will set the same value for their mat-select. This is the ouput if I select option "Esito Analisi" for the first row:

[image]

How can I resolve this behaviour? And after, how can I get the value of the seleted option for each row, if I want to save the data?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution was very stupid, but I hope it will help someone. I set `[(value)]="documento.tipo"` instead of binding it to a "generic" variable. So in the end I have:

```
<tr *ngFor="let documento of documenti" class="mat-row">
                <td> {{documento.nome}} </td>
                <td> {{documento.note}} </td>
                <td> <mat-form-field class="col">
                    <mat-select [(value)]="documento.tipo">
                      <mat-option value="generico">Allegato Generico</mat-option>
                      <mat-option value="verbale">Verbale</mat-option>
                      <mat-option value="esito">Esito Analisi</mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                  </mat-form-field> </td>
                <td>
                    <button mat-button class="delete" (click)="rimuoviDaDocumenti(documento)">delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

and to get the selected option, in method "rimuoviDaDocumenti(documento)":

```
  rimuoviDaDocumenti(documento){
    console.log("Documento " + documento.tipo);
  }
```

where documenti is this array:

```
documenti = [
    {
    nome: "Doc 1",
    note: "notes",
    tipo: ""
  },
  {
    nome: "Doc 2",
    note: "notes",
    tipo: ""
  }
```